# How to Clear the RealmResults<> of a particular Query while Filtering through the Realm in Android?

Tags: android, realm

I am applying filters on realm using RealmResults<>.

I begin to do like this -

```
RealmResults<data> filteredRealmResults;
List<data> tranfilteredlist;

private OrderedRealmCollectionChangeListener<RealmResults<data>> filteredTransChangeListener =
            new OrderedRealmCollectionChangeListener<RealmResults<data>>() {
                @Override
                public void onChange(RealmResults<data> results, OrderedCollectionChangeSet changeSet) {

                    Log.d("realm", "filteredRealmResults.size():" + filteredRealmResults.size());

                    tranfilteredlist = results;
                    initFilterAdapter();

                }
            };
```

Now I want to delete the `filteredRealmResults`. I did like this -

```
void deleteFilteredRealmResults() {

        realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
            @Override
            public void execute(Realm realm) {

                // Delete all matches
                filteredRealmResults.deleteAllFromRealm();
            }
        });
    }
```

After doing this my data in the realm got deleted. So I just try to delete the `tranfilteredlist` but it throws an exception that it does not support `.clear();`

I want to clear if from the memory whatever is holder the query data. Correct me if I am wrong or doesn't understand or just worrying too much.

I read **This class holds all the matches of a RealmQuery for a given Realm. The objects are not copied from the Realm to the RealmResults list, but are just referenced from the RealmResult instead. This saves memory and increases speed.**

Answer (score 1):

> I want to clear if from the memory whatever is holder the query data.
>   Correct me if I am wrong or doesn't understand or just worrying too
>   much.

Once you invoke `filteredRealmResults.deleteAllFromRealm`, it [will clear the internal resultant elements object](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/blob/master/realm/realm-library/src/main/java/io/realm/OrderedRealmCollectionImpl.java#L220)(which holds the elements) and as you know, resultant objects are reference so data will be deleted from realm database too. Hence, there is no need to call `clear` on the `RealmResults` object.

You can verify this by calling `filteredRealmResults.size()` after deletion, it will return `0`.

> I just try to delete the tranfilteredlist but it throws an exception
>   that it does not support .clear();

It is the expected behaviour as [clear has been deprecated](https://realm.io/docs/java/3.0.0/api/io/realm/RealmResults.html#clear--) so don't use it.

> Why deprecated?

1. `deleteAllFromRealm` automatically clears the list so no need to call it again explicitly.
2. Calling `clear` on `RealmResults` object will result in deletion of data from database, can cause unexpected behaviour if the user is not aware so API is being modified to avoid unexpected behaviours.